# Algorithm of replacing line indexes

Tags: javascript, algorithm, text, alignment

In general:

I have a text

```
Sample1 Text1 Line 1
Sample2 Text2 Line 2
Sample3 Text3 Line 3
```

and an array `['LEFT', 'RIGHT', 'CENTER']` which represents the Alignments..

Assume, I removed `Line 1 Sample2` which makes text to be:

```
Sample1 Text1 
Text2 Line 2
Sample3 Text3 Line 3
```

The Alignment array should remain the same: `['LEFT', 'RIGHT', 'CENTER']`
But, if I remove the second line, the array should change to be `['LEFT','CENTER']`

And vise versa... when adding a line between line 1 and two, it should change an array to be `['LEFT', 'LEFT', 'RIGHT', 'CENTER']` by taking an alignment from the "extended" line...

Yeah... I know... confusing...

https://jsfiddle.net/redlive/yuz08axc/

Comment: I don't need to add \n... that's the point...
When text changes, I need to RE-BUILD text alignments and apply them based on new values.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this

```js
let text = 'a\nb\nc\n'
const textAsArray = text.split('\n')
const alignments = ['left', 'right', 'center']

// initial
console.log('initial state:', text, alignments)

// remove second line
removeLine(1)
console.log('removed second line:', text, alignments)


// add second line
addLine(1, 'b')
console.log('added second line:', text, alignments)

function removeLine(num) {
  textAsArray.splice(num,1)
  alignments.splice(num,1)
  text = textAsArray.join('\n')
}


function addLine(num, val) {
  textAsArray.splice(num, 0, val)
  alignments.splice(num, 0, alignments[num ? num - 1 : 'left' /* left is default */ ])
  text = textAsArray.join('\n')
}
```

Comment: Not exactly... what you do is you operating Alignments Array and then text, but I need it to work based on Text Changes...
Once you changed text - rebuild the Alignment Array.

Comment: I showed you the general principle. Writing the whole thing is resource-demanding, Stackoverflow is not about that, but rather about giving a direction. The whole thing can be quite complex. String diff library should be involved as well if you want to know which line was removed or added. e.g. [this](https://github.com/kpdecker/jsdiff). After you manage to implement string-diff, you can almost just drop-in my code. If my answer was any helpful/correct, consider upvoting it and selecting as the best, because I spent my time, you know. And I think I've answered to the question as it was.

Comment: Nubor, thank you but it wasn't the solution I was looking for... sorry...

Comment: @EugeneVilder It's interesting that upvoting and selecting doesn't cost you anything (you'd actually get +2 points), yet you behave so miserly. In the end I've answered your question as it was laid out but it turned out that you formed it incorrectly.